# How do you split a string into individual characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am doing this challenge:

Question:

> **It's 1868 and you've just bought a telegraph key so you can transmit messages in Morse code directly to your friend using a personal
> telegraph line. We've given you a file morsecode.txt which translates
> from any character (except a space) to its code. When a message is
> written in Morse code, characters are separated by spaces, while
> actual spaces are written as slash (/) in coded messages.**

I want to split the input string into individual characters and verify it with the code in the file.

my code:

```
data = {}
with open('morsecode.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    key, value = line.split()
    data[key] = (value)
  
code = input('Message: ').lower()
```

The desired output:
[image: desired output]

I can't share the text file in stackoverflow for some reason

here's the text in the file:

A .-

B -...

C -.-.

D -..

E .

F ..-.

G --.

H ....

I ..

J .---

K -.-

L .-..

M --

N -.

O ---

P .--.

Q --.-

R .-.

S ...

T -

U ..-

V ...-

W .--

X -..-

Y -.--

Z --..

0 -----

1 .----

2 ..---

3 ...--

4 ....-

5 .....

6 -....

7 --...

8 ---..

9 ----.

. .-.-.-

, --..--

? ..--..

- -....-

/ -..-.

: ---...

' .----.

- -....-

) -.--.-

; -.-.-

( -.--.

= -...-

@ .--.-.

Comment: Can you share the content of ```morsecode.txt```

Comment: `for each_char in message:
    # do your operation`

Comment: Strings in Python are iterable so you can run through them with for loops, list expressions etc

Comment: @Sujay I have added the file's contents to the post

Comment: Edit your  question, there's at least one syntax problem: `code = input('Message: ').lower ` needs a parenthesis `()` after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` dictionary is getting updated when you read from the text file, you can do the following:

```
code = input('Message: ').lower()
new_string = ' '.join(data[letter] for letter in code)
```

`.join` takes an iterable as an argument. You can fetch the particular value from the dictionary and pass them in `join`

Answer (score 0):

#1st define a dictionary

`

```
dic={...} # as your list above
tmp=''
for a in input():
    tmp=tmp+"".join(dic.get(a)) 
print(tmp)
```

`